# How to output JSON for WordPress search page using Relevanssi?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, relevanssi

I'm using the WordPress search plugin [Relevanssi](https://www.relevanssi.com/).

I'm trying to customise my `search.php` template to output JSON, like so:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$results = array();

if (have_posts()):
  while (have_posts()): 
    the_post();
    $results[] = array(
      'permalink' => get_permalink(),
      'title' => get_the_title()
    );
  endwhile;
endif;

echo json_encode($results);

die();

?>
```

However, I'm getting an error that headers are already sent.

> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/NBC/wp-content/plugins/relevanssi/lib/search.php:554)
>   in **/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/NBC/wp-content/themes/NBC/search.php** on
>   line 3

Is there a better way to do this? The reason I need it as JSON is that I want to consume it with JS.

I have done this before on an older site, so perhaps the issues are with the latest version I'm using? `3.5.11`

Note that the query DOES return results, but I get these errors on the page too, which causes me to receive invalid JSON data back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevanssi 3.5.11 has a small bug. It doesn't affect the plugin use in any way, but with WP_DEBUG enabled, it throws a notice for an undefined variable. That's why you're seeing that "headers already sent" error.

If you want to keep WP_DEBUG enabled, you need to fix that bug. The fix is simple: add this to lib/search.php on line 382 to define the variable.

`$non_post_post_type = NULL;`

This fix will be included in the version 3.5.12.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by disabling the the WP_DEBUG, but since your answer is more thorough, you get the points! Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, disabling WP_DEBUG will remove the symptom (printing out the notice, causing the "Headers already sent" error), but not the actual problem, which is causing the notice in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The issue goes away if I turn off `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

It must be something to do with WordPress internals that I don't understand.